# Column changes from "WinorLoss" to "Class"

Tags: r, r-caret

I am working on constructing a logistic model on R (I am a beginner on R and am following a tutorial on building logistic models). I have done the following, everything works but when I complete the downsample function for some reason the column named "WinorLoss" changes to "Class" and I am sure this cause an issue with everything.

Could anyone please let me know if what I am doing makes sense or is there big errors I am making?

```
my_data <- read.csv('C:/Users/Magician/Desktop/R files/Fnaticfirstround.csv', header=TRUE)
my_data

str(my_data)

library(mlbench)
glm(Map ~ WinorLoss, family="binomial", data=my_data)

table(my_data$Map)
table(my_data$WinorLoss)

my_data$WinorLoss <- ifelse(my_data$WinorLoss == "W", 1,0)
my_data$WinorLoss <- factor(my_data$WinorLoss, levels = c(0,1))

my_data

table(my_data$WinorLoss)

library(caret)
'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')
options(scipen=999)

set.seed(100)
trainDataIndex <- createDataPartition(my_data$WinorLoss, p=0.7, list=F)
trainData <- my_data[trainDataIndex, ]
testData <- my_data[-trainDataIndex, ]

trainData
testData

table(trainData$WinorLoss)
table(testData$WinorLoss)

set.seed(100)
down_train <- downSample(x = trainData[, colnames(trainData) %ni% "WinorLoss"],
                         y = trainData$WinorLoss)
down_train
```

When running `trainData` the columns returned are Date, Event, opponent, Map, Score, WinorLoss, winner.. but when I run the downtrain function the columns become Date, Event, opponent, Map, Score, winner, Class

Help Please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, `downSample` and some of the other caret packages do that by default, unless specified otherwise.

If you have a question about a particular function try the manual packages first.

```
?downSample
```

If you do this you will see all of the arguments

```
downSample(x, y, list = FALSE, yname = "Class")
```

So by default the function will change the yname to "Class" which is what you are seeing.

Thus to get your desired output:

```
down_train <- downSample(x = trainData[, colnames(trainData) %ni% "WinorLoss"],
                         y = trainData$WinorLoss,
                         yname = "WinorLoss")
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, one other question if you know. Is there a way to filter my_data to select specific criteria.. 
E.g. Maps is a column in my_data but Maps consists of 8 different maps e.g. "Train", can I somehow gather the above just for "Train" and not all 8 maps?

Comment: @Kreeshee `library(dplyr); particular_map <- filter(my_data, Maps == "Specific Map")`. The other way is is `particular_map <- my_data[my_data[["Maps"]]=="Specific Map",]`. Also if the answer above answered your question, please select the checkmark on it so others know it works.